# Change image of a button (normal + pressed) with a function permanently

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, button

I want to change the background-image of a button, and of its :active form, with a function in javascript. The function gets executed ONCE, but this should change both background-images PERMANENTLY. For better understanding, here's code:

The button executes a click-count function.

```
<button onclick="counting()">
```

This click-count function executes the function I'm asking for after a certain amount of clicks:

```
var clicks = 0;
function counting() {
  clicks++;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;   
      if (clicks === 5) {      
      requestedFunction();
```

The button's background image is found in CSS:

```
button { background-image:url(button_normal.png);
background-size: cover;
```

and its :active form aswell:

```
button:active { background-image:(button_pressed.png);
background-size: 100%;
```

Since the button changes its image when active (you clicked the button), the background size is cover or 100%.

How can I replace "button_normal.png" and "button_pressed.png" with, for example, "giraffe.png" and "pig.png"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If can do in this way:

- add initial class to your button
- create two class one for initial state and one for modified state
- with js when you want to change the button remove the initial class and set the modified class

```html
<button class="myButton initial">My Button!</button>
```

```css
.initial {
  background-image:url(button_normal.png);
  background-size: 100%;
}

.initial:hover {
  background-image:url(button_pressed.png);
  background-size: 100%;
}

.modified {
  background-image:url(giraffe.png);
  background-size: 100%;
}

.modified:hover {
  background-image:url(pig.png);
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```js
  document.querySelector(".myButton").classList.remove('initial').add("modified");
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out! You wrote hover, but you mean :active right?

Comment: Okay, your solution doesn't work for me but it brought me on the right track: